# Smart Contracts developed for Ethereum can also be used in Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm newcomer to blockchain and i'm starting to develop a new token, and i've seen many places telling the similarities between the two blockchains. And i read that BSC have a EVM(Ethereum Virtual Machine) compatibility
My question is if that means If I follow a tutorial to learn do deploy a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain, written in Solidity. Will the same contract work in the Binance Smart Chain too? If not, what are the major diferrences when writting contracts for one and the other?
Thank you

Comment: Although I love the idea of discussing crypto, I don't think stack overflow specifically is a forum for pros and cons this broadly targeted so much as tangible solutions to specific problems.

Comment: @Atmas theres plenty of threads here discussing similar subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the same contract work in the Binance Smart Chain too?

Yes, actually if you developed a contract that works in ethereum, it will works in all the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) compatible chains. For getting started, I suggest you read the [solidity doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/), try the examples in [remix online ide](https://remix.ethereum.org/), and deploy to testnet (all the chains have testnet).

p.s. how to get the test coin? google search `testnet faucet`